# $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^m \mod 10$

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

With $S_{(n,m)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^m$, I study $S_{(n,m)}\mod 10$ for n=2021.
More than just solving this specific exercise, I would like to know what general reasoning would be wise for dealing with such problems.
My first ideas are to :

- search for common properties or links between $n \times(n+1) \over 2$, $n \times(n+1) \times (2 \times n +1) \over 6$, $\big({(n+1) \times (n+2) \over 2}\big)^2$ etc.
- search for 2021 properties...

Can somebody give me some advice in order to build an accurate reasoning ?

Thanks in advance.

Romain

[image: Examples]

Comment: Since you only care about the sum $\pmod {10}$, you really only need to compute $\sum_{k=0}^9 k^m \pmod {10}$.  After that it's just simple arithmetic.

Comment: Correction:  since your sum starts at $k=1$, not $k=0$, you should start by computing $\sum_{k=1}^{10} k^m \pmod {10}$.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $S_{n,m}$ is the sum, and that we are looking for $S_{n,m} \operatorname{mod} 10$.  If we know $S_{n,m} \operatorname{mod} 2$ and $S_{n,m} \operatorname{mod} 5$, the we can get $S_{n,m} \operatorname{mod} 10$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Since $k^m$ is even if and only if $k$ is even, modulo $2$ the value just depends on the number of odd positive integers $\leq n$.  This is odd when $n$ is if the form $4k+1$ and even for $n$ of the form $4k+3$.  Since $2021=4\cdot505+1$, $S_{2021,m}\equiv1\operatorname{mod} 2$ for all $m\geq1$.

To get $S_{n,m} \operatorname{mod} 5$, note that for all $k$ and $m$ we have $k^{m+4}\equiv k^m\operatorname{mod} 5$ by Fermat's little theorem, so we only need to compute the answers for $m=0,1,2,3$.  Since you know the values of $S_{n,m}$ for these values of $m$, and $2021\equiv1\operatorname{mod} 5$, it will be easy to finish.

I leave that up to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. "I assume that $S_(n,m)$ is the sum, and that we are looking for $S_(n,m)$ mod 10". Yes, that's it : I modified the title of my question that was incorrect.

Comment: Hi, I know that an odd positive integer is of the form $2k+1$. But how would you demonstrate that the number of odd positive integers $\leq n$ is odd when n is of the form $4k+1$ or $4k+2$ ?

Comment: @Romain The odd integers $\leq4n+1$ are the integers $2k+1$ for $k=0,1,\dots,2n$ so there are $2n+1$ of them.

Comment: Thank you. I begin understanding. How would you calculate the number of odd integers $\leq4n+2$ ?

Comment: Since $4n+2$ is even, it's the same as the number $\leq 4n+1$

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feel it so easy and hard in the same time !

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $k^5 \equiv k \bmod 10$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: This hint helped me finish my demonstration but I was wondering how do you prove it ?

Comment: @Just check that it hold for $k=0,\dots9$. Or use Fermat mod $5$ and the Chinese remainder theorem